# Is it possible to draw moving meshes only in WebGL?

Tags: performance, webgl

there is a car in my scene. Only the wheels is moving, but I still need to draw the other parts of the car.

I am wondering if there is any way to draw the moving part only so that the performance can be improve hugely.

[image]

Comment: If you use the preserveDrawingBuffer attribute in your getContext call, then WebGL won’t clear the frame buffer between calls, so you can draw on top of your previous frame.  But you’ll still need to do something to erase the previous frame’s wheels!  You may want to draw the car’s body to a FBO just once at startup, and then in your frame drawing function, put that predrawn body in your frame and then draw just the wheels on top of it.

Comment: You could render it without the moving parts to a texture (also create a copy of the depthbuffer) and start from there. Instead of clearing the color/depth buffer each frame, you copy the pre-rendered parts as a start.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Thanks for your help.